# Get selected values of multiple cloned array

Tags: jquery

Im having problem on getting the values of multiple checkbox cloned array.

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(e) {
    var name = $(this).attr('name');


    var addons = $.map($(':checkbox[name="'+name+'"\\[\\]]:checked'), function(n, i){
        return n.value;
    }).join(',');


    alert(addons);


});
```

Heres my html page:

```
<input id="addons1" class="addons" type="checkbox" value="Baby Cot" name="addons1[]">
<input id="addons2" class="addons" type="checkbox" value="Balloon Ride" name="addons1[]">
<input id="addons1" class="addons" type="checkbox" value="Baby Cot" name="addons2[]">
<input id="addons2" class="addons" type="checkbox" value="Balloon Ride" name="addons2[]">
<input id="addons1" class="addons" type="checkbox" value="Baby Cot" name="addons3[]">
<input id="addons2" class="addons" type="checkbox" value="Balloon Ride" name="addons3[]">
```

When i try to alert the values, it gets the previous click values of the previous element and append to the current one.

Comment: FYI, IDs ***must*** be unique on document context

Comment: Looks like you are using wrong selector, it should be `$(':checkbox[name="'+name+'"]:checked')` but then quite unclear the behaviour you are describing. Don't you have already onchange event bound on not cloned checkboxes? You should replicate your issue online

Comment: Hi Wolf, when i try to alert the values, using the first name="addons1", it gives me the correct value "Baby Cot,Balloon Ride", but when i try to click the other checkbox like for example name="addons2", it gives me this value "Baby Cot,Balloon Ride,Baby Cot,Balloon Ride", it should not be appending on the previous element.

Comment: It doesn't here: http://jsfiddle.net/20ycahgt/  But again, this is invalid HTML markup, see my first comment

Comment: hi Wolf, after following your comment/solutions it works well on my side, thank you